# Continuous log-rotated tcpdump - dealing with interface disconnections

Tags: tcpdump

I'm currently running a continuous `tcpdump` job with the following command:

`tcpdump -pni en4 -G 3600 -w 'data/trace_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap'`

It runs very well over long periods of time, creating one `pcap` file per hour.

However if there is any kind of disruption to the physical link, `tcpdump` exits with the following error:

`tcpdump: pcap_loop: The interface went down`

Is there any way for `tcpdump` to remain running despite the intermittent physical interface disconnection? If not, what strategy would you suggest to catch this error and restart `tcpdump` on interface reconnection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not wrap it with bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
   echo tcpdump restarted at $(date)
   tcpdump -pni en4 -G 3600 -w 'data/trace_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap'
   sleep 3
done
```

This will keep tcpdump running

Comment: This would definitely work. The only downside is that I like to keep the log files started at the hour mark (I start the tcpdump with the `at` command, which then rotates the files every 60 minutes). Using the bash script would mean switching to a logrotate solution as opposed to the `-G` flag.